# Materialize CSS modals not working with Flask + Jinja2 templates

Tags: jquery, html, css, materialize

I am building a Flask App + Jinja2 Templates. In this app, I have a page that has a floating action button which will expand to show an upload button. I want to show a model which includes a form to select files to upload.

I have followed the official documentation [here](http://materializecss.com/modals.html#!) and also checked out this [example](http://codepen.io/mblarsen/pen/JXPRjY) but still no luck.

The modal is hidden but it doesn't show up when the button is clicked. what am I getting wrong?

```
<html>

     <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}"  media="screen,projection"/>
        <title>{{folder_name}}</title>
        <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
    // the "href" attribute of .modal-trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
    $('.modal-trigger').leanModal();


  });
          </script>
      </head>

    <body>
        {% include 'navbar.html' %}
        <table class="highlight">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Date Modified</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            {% for file in files %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{file['name']}}</td>
              <td>{{file['modified']}}</td>

            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>

        <div id="uploadModal" class="modal">
              <div class="modal-content">
                  <form action="#">
                    <div class="file-field input-field">
                      <div class="btn">
                        <span>File</span>
                        <input type="file" multiple>
                      </div>
                      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
                        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
        </div>


        <div class="fixed-action-btn">
          <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
            <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
          </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="btn-floating modal-trigger green" href="#uploadModal"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>


    </body>


</html>
```

Comment: Works for me http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrMjNZ

Comment: Thanks for checking it out.. I am still not sure why it's not working with me

Comment: If you can't reproduce it for us, all we can do is guess. *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].*

Comment: I am not doing anything that's not mentioned in the description. However, I will look at the guide you referenced and revise my question structure.

Comment: Well, we don't need the entire page and your template code and you didn't reproduce the problem - you just posted your HTML structure. And in this HTML structure, you don't have the materialize CSS, jquery or the materialize JS library. Or are you not including those? I'm assuming you are. We need the *minimal* amount of code to *reproduce the problem*. Use CDN links to jquery and materialize to reproduce your setup for us and remove any unnecessary code that isn't relevant to the question.